# Understanding HashJoin in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, hash

Let's consider the following query:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM foo JOIN bar ON foo.c1=bar.c1;
```

Where

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
  c1 integer,
  c2 text
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE bar
(
  c1 integer,
  c2 boolean
)
```

As explained in this [article](http://www.dalibo.org/_media/understanding_explain.pdf)

> PostgreSQL does a sequential scan of table bar, and computes the hash
>   for  each of its rows. Then, it does a sequential scan of foo, and for
>   each row, computes the hash of the row and compares it to the bar
>   hashed table. **If it matches, the row will be put in the resulting** 
>   **set.** If it doesn't match, the row is skipped.

Here is the plan:

```
Hash Join  (cost=13463.00..49297.00 rows=500000 width=42) (actual time=95.634..1001.306 rows=500000 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (foo.c1 = bar.c1)
  Buffers: shared hit=3850 read=6697
  ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..18334.00 rows=1000000 width=37) (actual time=0.026..135.609 rows=1000000 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=1637 read=6697
  ->  Hash  (cost=7213.00..7213.00 rows=500000 width=5) (actual time=95.478..95.478 rows=500000 loops=1)
        Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 18067kB
        Buffers: shared hit=2213
        ->  Seq Scan on bar  (cost=0.00..7213.00 rows=500000 width=5) (actual time=0.004..37.040 rows=500000 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=2213
Total runtime: 1017.572 ms
```

The thing that I couldn't understand is how is it determined if the row should be in result set. The fact that hashes are equals doesn't mean that the rows satisfy the predicate `foo.c1=bar.c1`.

***Question:*** So, after comparing hashes, we should check if the predicate satisfied? Also, Is it neccesary that each bucket contains rows with the same hash?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.depesz.com/2013/05/09/explaining-the-unexplainable-part-3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. So, after comparing hashes, we should check if the predicate satisfied?

Yes.

Hash join uses join attributes as hash keys. When hash function values of two rows are equal, we must (a) check that join attributes are actually equal, and (b) check that other join qualifications are satisfied too.

In your example join attributes are `foo.c1` and `bar.c1`, and there are no other join qualifications.

More complex example: `SELECT * FROM foo JOIN bar ON foo.c1 = bar.c1 AND foo.c1 > bar.c1;`. In this case we still can use hash join on `=` operator, but in addition have to check `foo.c1 > bar.c1`.

If you're interested in details, look into the source code (start with [nodeHashjoin.c](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/executor/nodeHashjoin.c)).

---

2. Is it neccesary that each bucket contains rows with the same hash?

It is true by definition, isn't it? Hash function maps keys to indexes in hash table, i. e. to bucket numbers.

But strictly speaking, not *rows with the same hash*, but *join attributes with the same hash*.

Comment: Thanks much for your answer, especially for the reference to source code. But may I ask you one more question. As far as I got from your answer, we have a hashtable consisiting of _**attributes**_ which in our case is just `foo.c1` (a hashtable for the table `foo`). But what if we have more complex one like `Hash Cond: ((foo.c1 = baz.c1) AND (foo.c2 = baz.c2))`. Will the `hashtable` for `foo` consist of tuples of `(foo.c1, foo.c2)` in that case?

Comment: At some level of detail, yes. Though I'm not sure about implementation details. Source code is the answer...

Answer (score 2):

The quote is misleading. It is not "the hash of the row" but rather "the hash value associated with the row". Not the complete row is being hashed, only some parts of it are. More specifically: Only values from columns which occur in the ON clause of the join are hashed. Now of course looking for matching hashes in both tables is exactly what needs to be done for a join operation.

And yes, obviously one has to check if the those hashed values are actually equal, because hash collisions are possible.